# Phoegap/Cordova to load specific DB row after AJAX GET

Tags: html, ajax, cordova, mysqli, phonegap

Im building an app using PHoneGap as the compiler so using HTML5, CSS, JQuery, AJAX etc. Ive manage to get AJAX to GET all the rows from the Database perfectly well, as I have to use .HTML extension on my files I'm struggling to be able to link through to specific DB record. I can do this perfectly in PHP. Im struggling with the HTML part.

Here is my AJAX Loader to get all Rows from DB

```js
var inProcessVideos = false;//Just to make sure that the last ajax call is not in process
setTimeout( function () {
    if (inProcessVideos) {
        return false;//Another request is active, decline timer call ...
    }
    inProcessVideos = true;//make it burn ;)
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://MY-URL.COM/videos-mysql.php', //Define your script url here ...
        data: '', //Pass some data if you need to
        method: 'POST', //Makes sense only if you passing data
        success: function(answer) {
            jQuery('#videos-modules').html(answer);//update your div with new content, yey ....
            inProcessVideos = false;//Queue is free, guys ;)
        },
        error: function() {
            //unknown error occorupted
            inProcessVideos = false;//Queue is free, guys ;)
        }
    });
}, 500 );
```

And here is the contents of the PHP File that renders all the Results from the Database. This part displays the content perfectly.

```html
<?php
include ("../config/mysqli_connect.php");

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM videos");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "
<a href='" . $row["id"]. "'>
<div class='video-module'>
 <div class='video-thumb'><img src='https://MY-URL.COM/thumbs/" . $row["video_thumb"]. "'></div>
 <div class='video-thumb-details'>
  <div class='video-thumb-title'>&nbsp;" . $row["id"]. " - " . $row["video_title"]. "</div>
" . $row["publisher_name"]. "
</div>
 </div></a>


  ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}


?>
```

After the ECHO statement I would normally put something like video-Profile.php?id=$id and it would go to that page and pull in that record from the Database.

However now that I have to do it only in HTML, and im assuming AJAX, how to I achieve this.

Here is the PHP and the MYSQL Query to GET the specific record from the Database. Its currently in MYSQL, I will convert it to MYSQLi once I've got it working and got my head around it.

```html
<?php
// Use the URL 'id' variable to set who we want to query info about
$id = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['id']); // filter everything but numbers for security
if ($id == "") {
 echo "Missing Data to Run";
 exit();
}
//Connect to the database through our include 
include_once "../config/connect_to_mysql.php";
// Query member data from the database and ready it for display
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($count > 1) {
 echo "There is no user with that id here.";
 exit(); 
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$id = $row["id"];
$video_title = $row["video_title"];
$video_thumb = $row["video_thumb"];
$publisher_name = $row["publisher_name"];
$video_directory = $row["video_directory"];
$video_path = $row["video_path"];
$upload_date = $row["upload_date"];
$video_views = $row["video_views"];

}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <?php echo ("$id");?> - <?php echo ("$video_thumb");?>

</body>
</html>
```

I know this works if I'm running PHP files, and my server is set to PHPv5.3., but before I make it live, it will be sorted to MYSQLi and run on PHP7???

Im looking for inspiration to get this to function via HTML only files.

thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty brutalistic way of doing this - typically you'd return `JSON` or similar from the PHP and then process this into the HTML elements within your JS. But for this case you can do this:

```
//within call
success: function(answer) {
    var contents = jQuery(answer); // You have now converted the HTML into a jquery model

    contents.filter(function(element){
       return $(element).attr('id') === id
    }) // This allows you to search your child elements and pick them based on criteria
    jQuery('#videos-modules').html(contents); // now assign the remaining elements into your html as before

},
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It’s greatly appreciated. I e added your code to my Ajax request, not working yet, I’ll give it another try when I finish work.

Comment: Do you recommend an easier way of doing this? Or simpler way of doing this? I’m not expecting it to be done for me, just need pointing in the right direction.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have Tried this but i cant seem to find out how to Run a Console Log as it is Run on iOS iPad at the moment. Can not get it to render in the Browser.

```js
var inProcessVideos = false;//Just to make sure that the last ajax call is not in process

setTimeout( function () {
    if (inProcessVideos) {
        return false;//Another request is active, decline timer call
    }
    inProcessVideos = true;//make it burn ;)
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://MYURL.COM/appFiles/tablet/video-profile.php', //Define your script url here ...
        data: '', //Pass some data if you need to
        method: 'GET', //Makes sense only if you passing data
   success: function(answer) {
    var contents = jQuery(answer); // You have now converted the HTML into a jquery model

    contents.filter(function(element){
       return $(element).attr('id') === id;
    });
    jQuery('#videoProfile').html(answer);//update your div with new content, yey ....
            inProcessVideos = false;//Queue is free, guys ;)
        },

    });
}, 500 );
```

Struggling with this, i've looked at all the JQuery, AJAX MySQL web sites i can find including W3Schools, Jquery.com and many others. Just can not get it to pass  the ID to the PHP file to get the Record from the DB via AJAX.

My Links in the first JQuery AJAX Call are:

```html
<a href='video-Profile.html' data='".$row["id"]."' value='".$row["id"]." '>Some HTML STUFF/Images/Text etc</a>
```

I can get the ID and the First AJAX Call to show ALL the rows in the DB Table. Now just need to show Record by ID. This is what i cant get my head around. And it must be in .HTML Page as its an App compiled via PhoneGap. I know im repeating my self, Just not to sure if im making my point clear.  Thanks for the help in advance.